# Laravel 8 - MS SQL - Query Builder - using DB Raw. Trying to get the code right to make it work like the working MSSQL code

Tags: php, sql-server, laravel-8

How do I write this in Laravel to get the query below to work?

**Working Query:**

```
select  
fname,
lname,
title,
case when picture IS NULL then 'https://www.aaa.com/images/interior/bench2.jpg' else
'https://www..aaa.com/images/staff/' + REVERSE(LEFT(REVERSE(picture), CHARINDEX('/',REVERSE(picture)) - 1)) end as picture
from Staff
```

**One of my many tries**

```
  $faculties =
  DB::table('tblFaculty')->
  select(
    ['Fname',
    'Lname',
    'title',
    DB::raw('(case when picture IS NULL then "https://www2.aaa.com/images/interior/bench2.jpg"
    else "https://www2.aaa.com/images/facultystaff/" end) as picture')])->get();
  dd($faculties);
```

Thanks for any help. I have tried to make the question as clear as possible.

Comment: I am getting close I think.  I am having an issue with the CHARINDEX because it seems to need the '/'  - single quote inside of the raw('')  tried escaping etc.

Answer (score 1):

**Just in case someone needs this kind of help here is what finally worked.**

```
  $faculties =
  DB::table('tblFaculty')->
  select(
    ['Fname',
    'Lname',
    'title',
    'picture',
    DB::raw("(case when (picture IS NULL) then
    'https://www.aaa.com/images/interior/bench2.jpg' else
    'https://www.aaa.com/images/facultystaff/' + reverse(left(reverse(picture), CHARINDEX('/', REVERSE(picture)) - 1))
    end) as pictureUrl")])->get();

  dd($faculties);
```